# Using Time Manager with joined layers?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am trying to create an animation using Time Manager for multiple vector layers.

Each layer is a graduated map of rent prices for a quarter of a year.

I have 8 quarters, each in a separate layer. 4 for 2016, 4 for 2017. I would like to run an animation that shows rent prices in Q1 2016 and runs until Q4 2017.

My layers have no date column. So I imported a csv with dates for each quarter, e.g. for Q1 2017 there is a column Q1_2017 with the value 2017-01-01 and I computed a join to this csv for each of the 8 vector layers to give them a unique date column.

When I run time manager I am adding a layer with the following settings:

[image: time manager settings]

When I add all my layers in a similar way and try to run the animation I get an error like the below:

[image: error]

Is it my settings or is it the join?

Does the date field need to be in the vector layer itself?

Comment: Images aren't searchable, so others with the same error message won't be able to find your question. Please add the error as text instead of as an image.

Answer (score 1):

TimeManager doesn't support joined fields. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/148).

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3.14, you can use the  `Layer/Properties/Temporal` to set the temporal extents of your data, `Project/Properties/Temporal` to control the temporal extent of your project, and use the Temporal Controller (`View/Panels/Temporal Controller` temporally control the visibility of the layers:
[image: QGIS options for controlling a layer's temporal extent]

[image: Project temporal extents]

[image: Temporally controlled view]