# How to join shapefile to CSV (not other way around)?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a CSV with multiple rows per county (it contains data on number of coronavirus cases per week). I want to make a choropleth map showing the change over time, but when I join this data to a county shapefile in QGIS, it only preserves the most recent datapoint. How do I execute a join such that all of the rows in the time series CSV are preserved, but have a geometry attribute? Ideal output is a geojson.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a wkt field in the shapefile using the geom_to_wkt( $geometry ) command, and joined this column to the CSV with attribute data. I then re-imported the CSV using the well-known-text field to generate geometry attributes, and was able to pretty easily export this CSV to a geoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at existing answer from [Using Time Manager with joined layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296304/using-time-manager-with-joined-layers), it redirects you to a Github issue related to your question. In this issue, the solution is about using virtual layers (as stated at https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/148#issuecomment-463218771)

The link to a tutorial to use virtual layers (from the issue) you need to look at is https://anitagraser.com/2017/01/17/small-multiples-for-od-flow-maps-using-virtual-layers/

After joining, you can export the layer to GeoJSON

With QGIS 3.14, time manager has been integrated in QGIS itself and it seems to worked with joined fields (untested on my side).